# Bash script to move multiple files with fragment '(2)' in filename into a separate folder (macos screenshots)

Tags: macos, screen-capture

When taking screenshots on MacOS, the second monitor content is in file xxxx(2).png

If a user (poweruser on Windows but newbie on MacOS) wants a script that moves all screenshot with `*(2).*` to folder "two", how is it done via script/command line?

The command below does not work.  It moves all files and the user needs just half of the files moved.

```
mkdir two
mv *(2).* two
```

What is the correct mv command?

Files containing `(2)` fragment in file name (at the end of the name) need to be moved.

Example of file name from second monitor is 'ssht 2022-04-27 at 12.19.55 PM (2).png'.  That need to be moved.

Example of file from first monitor is ssht 2022-04-27 at 12.19.55 PM.png

(and ideally making it clickable/executable (chmod or .command or bash mymovecmd.sh)

`man mv` does not talk at all about any star notation for moving files. Not sure if mv on macos suports globbing and how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176590/what-do-double-asterisk-wildcards-mean

Comment: `mkdir two;find . -name '*(2)*' -exec mv '{}' two \;` but I have little idea why is this correct

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards/patterns are handled by your shell usually (`mv` for instance doesn't know anything about patterns in filenames, that's why you can have file names with `*` in them), so in the case of

```
mv *(2).* two
```

your shell tries to expand `*(2).*` before `mv` is even called. Because `*(2)` has a special meaning in both `bash` and `zsh` (a different one though) this will not expand into something you would expect (run `echo *(2).*` to see what it actually does).

You can prevent this by escaping the paranthesis

```
mv *\(2\).* two
```

PS: The reason the `find` command works is because in this case the regexp is handled by `find` itself (as you put it in `''` and `find` needs to handle regexps itself to expand them for each item it scans).